# create a jsp file according to an existing servlet

Tags: java, jsp, url-parameters

i'm new to jsp , i have already a servlet that works , it sends parametres in the url (url/servletname?name=test&msg=test2), but i want to make a jsp file that transform that to be visual, i don't know how to start , here's is my servlet :

```
package mypackage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import java.util.*;
//import ma.cloud.ParticipantDao;

public class infoservlet extends HttpServlet{

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");

        String p_name=req.getParameter("name");
        String p_msg=req.getParameter("message");

        String p_resp_text="";

        if (p_id !=null && p_response !=null){

            try {
                Demand_aide_dao dao=new MemeCache_Demande_aide();
                dao.respond_demande_aide_by_id(p_id, p_response);
                p_resp_text="Hi Mr." + p_name + " }";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                p_resp_text="message : error" + e.getMessage()+ " }";           
            }           
        }     
        resp.getWriter().println(p_resp_text);      
    }
}
```

i just need an idea on how to start, and how to turn it from a parametres in url to values that i can type it . please i'm stuck for 5 days now

Answer (score 0):

> Params to type, ' transform that to be visual'

Do you mean a form ?

In a text file type :

```
   <html>
   <body>
   <form action=/path/to/your/servlet/infoservlet  method=post name=f1>
   <input type=text name="name">
   <input type=text name=" message">

   <input type=submit value="Go">
   </form>
```

Save this as start.html or start.jsp (at this point there is no difference as the jsp does not have any jsp specific code, but later can add other elements to it).

In folder where your web content goes (depends what app container you are using for Jboss 5 free version can put it in :

> jbossMain\server\default\deploy\ROOT.war\

And start jboss with default :

> jbossMain/bin/run.sh -c default

Open this jsp in browser, type values press Go, by default jboss would start with port 8080 make sure no other service us running on same port before.

> `http://localhost:8080/start.jsp`

You need to go thru a tutorial on starting web apps and java jsps.
See 
 * https://www.google.com/search?q=java+jsp+tutorial
 * http://www.jsptut.com/
 * http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/

Comment: thanks for the websites, I'v meant that instead of entering the values in the url like that : url/servletname?name=test&msg=test2
i want to make a pge that have a input text.. so i can enter my values theres and when i pres send it goes and do the work of the servlet i have ....(notice i'm using memcache ..)

Comment: yes that is called a html form and i have given you an example of that in my code

Comment: see the answer now the code wsa not escaped/ marked as code so was not showibg earlier

Comment: What a poor answer. OP asked how to create a JSP to submit to the given servlet, not how to create a HTML to submit to some JSP. You seem also to never have read the message formatting rules nor pay a bit more love to English in spite of being a member for almost 1 year.